# Interesting algorithm to compare two matrices?

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I have a problem, basically, I have two matrices (vectors), one massive matrix and a smaller matrix. I have an algorithm that splits the massive matrix into blocks (of the size of the small block)

So for example (I am using test data here) so the massive matrix size is: 4x4 and the small matrix is 2x2 and then I pass the particular block (at the current position) to a function that checks to see if the small matrix is equal to the massive block (at that particular position) if it is, then returns true otherwise returns false.

I can output each block like this:

```
bool compareMatrix(vector<double> &theMatrix1, vector<double> &theMatrix2, int startRow, int startCol)
{
      // I can output the matrix blocks like this:
      cout << theMatrix1[startRow*2+startCol] << endl;    
}
```

But I don't quite understand how I would compare the block (at the startingRow/Col) to the small matrix..

How it would is this:
Matrix 1: (4x4)

```
0 1 0 1 
1 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 
0 1 1 1
```

Matrix 2: (2x2)

```
0 1 
0 1
```

I then split the blocks into 2x2:

B1 =

```
0 1 
1 1
```

is B1 equal to theMatrix2 - No so return false

B2 =

```
0 1
0 1
```

is B2 equal to theMatrix2 - Yes so return true

I have really tried to explain things to the best of detail as I possibly can and hope someone can give me some advice because I've been working on it for so long now!

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to check if smaller matrix is 'contained' in larger somehow?  A more rigorous problems statement would help you get feedback I think.

Comment: you could define a `BOOL areEqual = true` then loop through all elements and compare them individually, if two elements are not the same you can set `areEqual = false` and break out of the loop.

Comment: 4x4 matrix has four 2x2 matrices? or nine?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the big matrix is known you can compare small parts of it with your 2x2 matrix like so

```
int bigMatrixSize=4;

bool compare(...)
{
 for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    for (int k=0; k<2; ++k)
       if(bigMatrix[k+startX+(i+staryY)*bigMatrixSize] != smallMatrix[k][i])
           return false;
 return true;
}
```

I left out bounds checking and some other stuff, but It should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool compareMatrix(vector<double> &theMatrix1, int nRow1, int nCol1, vector<double> &theMatrix2, int nRow2, int nCol2, int startRow, int startCol)
{
    int p1 = startRow * nCol1 + startCol, p2 = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < nRow2; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < nCol2; ++x)
        {
            if (theMatrix1[p1 + x] != theMattrix2[p2 + x]) // You can use memcmp here, but it's safer let compiler do the optimization.
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        p1 += nCol1;
        p2 += nCol2;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You want something like this? You can add the columns count to the position to reach the next row.

Comment: What would nRow1, nCol1 pass though?

Comment: Just in case your matrices' size are not 4x4 and 2x2. Something like compareMatrix(m1, 4, 4, m2, 2, 2, 1, 1).